# Roblox - attempt to index nil with 'leaderstats'

Tags: lua, roblox

Can someone tell me how can I fix this error that shows up when I run my script? Thanks

```
line 4: Workspace.Slide1.PointsPart.Script:4: attempt to index nil with 'leaderstats'
```

```
script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    local player = hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")
    local plr = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent)
    if plr.leaderstats.Points.Value >= 0 then
        wait()
        script.Disabled = true
        script.Parent.Transparency = 1
        script.Parent.CanCollide = false
        plr.leaderstats.Points.Value = plr.leaderstats.Points.Value +5
        wait(0.5)
        script.Parent.Transparency = 1
        script.Parent.CanCollide = false
        script.Disabled = false
    end
end)
```

Answer (score 1):

The Touched event fires for anything that touches the part. You are not handling the case that a part isn't a child of a Player's Character.

```
local plr = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent)
if not plr then
    return
end

if plr.leaderstats.Points.Value >= 0 then
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change it to this

```lua
script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    local player = hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")
    local plr = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent)
    if plr and plr.leaderstats.Points.Value >= 0 then
        wait()
        script.Disabled = true
        script.Parent.Transparency = 1
        script.Parent.CanCollide = false
        plr.leaderstats.Points.Value = plr.leaderstats.Points.Value +5
        wait(0.5)
        script.Parent.Transparency = 1
        script.Parent.CanCollide = false
        script.Disabled = false
    end
end)
```

the compiler will calculate the instance "plr" first,

if it isn't nil, then the compiler will calculate "plr.leaderstats.Points.Value >= 0"

and this process called "Short-Circuit Evaluation"