# Atempted to index nil error when trying to find the playergui component of a player

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm trying to make a cutscene sorta thing for a dorr in roblox studio. My solution was to set up a collision detector on the door which would then make a gui template and set its parent to the playergui component.

I did this using the code

```
local afterIntoTransform = script.Parent.Parent.DoorUnion.Position.Z -6
local afterOutwardsTransform = script.Parent.Parent.DoorUnion.Position.Z + 6
local debounce = false

local function executeFadeSceneAndTpPlayer(player)
    local fadeScene = Instance.new("ScreenGui")
    local fadeSceneFrame = Instance.new("Frame")
    fadeScene.Name = "fadeScene"
    fadeSceneFrame.Name = "fadeFrame"
    fadeSceneFrame.Size = UDim2.new(1,0,1,0)
    fadeSceneFrame.Parent = fadeScene
    fadeSceneFrame.BorderSizePixel = 0
    fadeSceneFrame.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.new(1, 1, 1)
    fadeSceneFrame.BackgroundTransparency = 1
    print(game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(player).Name)
    fadeScene.Parent = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(player).PlayerGui
    for i = 0, 20, 1 do
        fadeSceneFrame.BackgroundTransparency -= 0.05
        wait(0.01)
    end
    player.HumanoidRootPart.Position = Vector3.new(player.HumanoidRootPart.Position.X, player.HumanoidRootPart.Position.Y, afterOutwardsTransform)
    for i = 0, 20, 1 do
        fadeSceneFrame.BackgroundTransparency += 0.05
        wait(0.01)
    end
    fadeScene:Destroy()
end

script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(hit) 
    if not debounce then
        debounce = true
        executeFadeSceneAndTpPlayer(hit.Parent)
        wait(0.2)
        debounce = false
    end
end)
```

It tells me: Attempted to index nil with name on line 15.

It works sometimes and sometimes doesnt but recently Ive noticed a trend that I can walk into the door then out again and then it breaks. I haven't coded in a while so I'm a little rusty but I hope I can get some help.

Answer (score 0):

You are running into the same issue as this person : [Roblox - attempt to index nil with 'leaderstats'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63622907/roblox-attempt-to-index-nil-with-leaderstats)

You are not accounting for the fact that the `Touched` event fires for every single part that touches it, and some of those parts might not belong to a player.

You can protect against this error by making sure that the object belongs to a player before you call `executeFadeSceneAndTpPlayer()`

```
script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    local plr = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent)
    if not plr then
        return
    end

    if not debounce then
        debounce = true
        executeFadeSceneAndTpPlayer(hit.Parent)
        wait(0.2)
        debounce = false
    end
end)
```